# How to remove the space between the header and the beginning of collapsible al Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would remove the space between the header and the beginning of the collapsible, I would appreciate if you can help

```
<div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header">
         <h1>Test</h1>
      </div>
          <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-corners="false">
          <div data-role="collapsible"> 
            <h3>Title</h3>       
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
          <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Title 2</h3>
            <p>Content 2</p>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

[Here is a link with a picture. I would remove the space between the header and the beginning of the collapsible][1]

```
  [1]: http://afines.com/foro/space.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

> "There's a 15px padding .... on the content div"

This appears to have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880897/how-to-remove-the-space-between-header-and-the-page-content-in-jquery) to some extent.  Also, when inspecting the `.ui-collapsible-set` element using Chrome's Developers tools option I found that there is provision for `margin` which is set at `.5em`.

In order to completely remove the space between a header and a collapsible-set the margin requires adjusting using the `<style>` tag:

`.ui-collapsible-set {
margin: 0 0;
}`