# How to remove the space between header and the page content in jquery?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to remove the space below the header and the first content , If you see the jsfiddle link . These is a space between the header "header" and "i'm list0" . I want to remove the space between them . So i have used

```
margin-top:5px;
```

for list, it doesn't work . so i tried for margin-bottom:-5px for header also ..It doesn;t work any case i have used.

http://jsfiddle.net/WPpfZ/25/

Comment: You have extra padding on `.ui-content`.  You can remove or change it.

Comment: Always post the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link (not even to jsFiddle). A fiddle is a nice adjunct, but not a replacement. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: Shouldn't the title of this question be "in jquery-mobile" rather than "in jquery"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a 15px padding, not on the header or the list, but on the content div that's around both list items. This will remove it:

```
.ui-content {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use:

```
.ui-content {
    padding-top: 0 !important;   
}
```

I've added the `!important` option just incase it's overwritten